# Navigate to inner page when on another page

Tags: flutter

How can I navigate to an inner page of a PageView when I'm on another page. For example: say I have the following pages:

- Home
- All Messages > Single Message Page
- Contact

When I'm on the Contact page, how can I go straight to the Single Message Page? I feel it's easiest to use named routing, so would love to have sucha sollution....

Comment: your 'Single Message Page' is a single page navigate from 'All Messages' using ListView?

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned in your own question, named routing would be the right way to do so.
With named routing, the route tree is much easier to understand and move around.

For Example, I defined in my main app widget, the exact routes in my app.
As you can see from the Flutter documentation:

```
MaterialApp(
  // Start the app with the "/" named route. In this case, the app starts
  // on the FirstScreen widget.
  initialRoute: '/',
  routes: {
    // When navigating to the "/" route, build the FirstScreen widget.
    '/': (context) => FirstScreen(),
    // When navigating to the "/second" route, build the SecondScreen widget.
    '/second': (context) => SecondScreen(),
  },
);
```

After you have defined the routes, you can move to this route by pushing a named route to the Navigator of your app.

```
// Within the `FirstScreen` widget
onPressed: () {
  // Navigate to the second screen using a named route.
  Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/second');
}
```

Read more at https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation/named-routes
Wish you luck!